# Fact table grain for data acquisition system

Tags: ssas

I have a network of data acquisition systems deployed around the country. Each system is  measuring the performance of a different building. Each system makes temperature, flow, speed, energy, and other types of measurements. The sampling rate varies from system to system; it can be as low as 5 seconds and as high as 15 minutes.

My objective is to store all the data in a SSAS databases for analysis purposes. However, I'm struggling to identify the appropriate grain and associated fact table and SSAS measure/measure group design.

My first question is, do any of the following have the same grain?:

- Data values with different units, such as temperature and energy values
- Data values with different sampling rates, such as temperature values sampled every minute and temperatures sampled every 15 minutes
- Data values recorded from different buildings, such as the indoor temperature at Building #1 and the indoor temperature recorded at Building #2
- Additive data values (such as energy) and non-additive data values (such as temperature)
- Two different measurements with the same units at a particular building, such as first floor temperature and second floor temperature.

If most or all of these examples do not have same grain, does this mean that each building's measurement should have a separate fact table in the relational data warehouse and a separate measure in the SSAS database? If yes, then I'd be looking at 1000 measures if we assume that I am studying 10 buildings with 100 measurements each. This doesn't seem right, but it also seems that I'm dealing with a data model that has many different measure grains.

Almost all of the examples I have found are related to finance or retail, which consist of measures that are obviously additive or countable, such dollar amounts or items. Therefore, the examples haven't been helping much.

Answer (score 1):

- Data values with different units can be at the same grain if they are collected with the same intersection of all dimensions (time, building, etc.). In the example, the temperature and energy values would be separate columns in the fact table. It would not be recommended to use a single fact column to represent measurements with different units.
- Data values with different sampling rates would not be at the same grain if you need to be able to report on both intervals simultaneously. However, if you can standardize your reports on the finer-grained interval, you could simply replicate the coarser-grained values into the finer-grained rows. For example, you could have a TemperaturePerMinute column and a TemperaturePer15Minute column, with the 15-minute interval value duplicated across all of the minute values within that interval. You would need to be careful when using aggregations (count, etc.) when reporting on the coarse-grained column, though. In addition, if you need to drill down to the sample level, you might need to use a separate fact table for each interval type.
- Data values from different buildings could certainly be recorded in a single fact table at the same grain. You would simply have a Building dimension that you link to your fact table for each measurement sample.
- In an OLAP model, measures are usually independent of each other, so additive and non-additive values can be represented at the same grain simply as separate columns.
- In this case, you would extend your Building dimension to include a Floor hierarchy and link your fact table records at the Floor grain. However, if you need to be able to link some samples to a Building and some samples to a Floor, then you may need to use a [parent-child dimension](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174846.aspx) (perhaps a Location dimension abstracting Buildings and Floors), to which you could link your fact table to either a Building or a Floor.

I have found that it helps to take a look at how you want to report on the data when the organization of the star schema is unclear. This should help to reduce the number of cubes that you have to create. In general, though, it's best not to try to normalize the OLAP model or make it too generic (i.e. using a single column to represent temperature and energy).